# jquery get value of element's grandchild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to grab the value of an `input` or `select` (selecting based on a grandparent's id), and test if it has been set/answered/responded to.

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li>Happy text</li>
    <li><input name="A" type="text" /></li>
    <li><input name="A" type="radio" value="01" />blah</li>
    <li><input name="A" type="radio" value="02" />blah</li>
</ul>

<ul id="bar">
    <li>Happy text</li>
    <li><input name="B" type="text" /></li>
    <li><input name="B" type="radio" value="01" />blah</li>
    <li><input name="B" type="radio" value="02" />blah</li>
</ul>

<ul id="baz">
    <li>Happy text</li>
    <li>
        <select name="C">
            <option value="" />
            <option value="01">blah</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried a few things in javascript (some more successful than others):

```
// question is the id of the grandparent
$("#"+question).find("input,select").val(); // this kind of works
$("#"+question).find("li").children().val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/2ttCF/

**Edit**: I don't want the values of elements that have been answered. I want to know what hasn't been answered. The code in the fiddle might explain it better.

Comment: Which input are you trying to get?  There are 3.

Comment: Whichever one has value (if text has been entered into the textfield, or if a radio has been checked, or if an option has been selected in a selection).

Comment: Why not just use a jQuery validation plugin?

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
$(':input').change(function(){
  $(this).addClass('changed');
});
```

By adding a class to each element after it has been changed, you can get all the elements that is not changed by this selector at a given time:

```
$(':input:not(.changed)');
```

Comment: Hi Jørgen, I'm actually trying to do the opposite (I want the ones that are empty/unselected/unchecked)

Comment: I changed my answer entirely, suggesting a different approach.

Comment: I think this is getting more complicated than it needs to be. What's happening in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/2ttCF/1/) when the button is clicked: `age=` (correct), `hispanic=0` (wrong), and `race=1` (wrong), and `state=undefined` (problem).

Comment: You could always select each element and check their values, but I doubt it'll be much less complicated than this.

Answer (score 0):

This one works ok:

```
$("#"+question).find(
    "input[type!='radio'],input[type='radio']:checked,select"
).val();
```

Comment: Hi kirilloid, I'm trying to do the opposite (I want the ones that aren't checked/selected)

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was already doing most of this already.

I ended up creating an array (`nonresponse`) and pushing the question names to it while looping thru the responses in a different part of the script:

It grabs all form elements and puts everything into an assoc array, then loops thru that array finding duplicate indexes and consolidates them into a single index whose value is an array:

```
responses = {
    "a": "val 1",
    "b": ["val 1","val 2","val 3"],
    "c": "", // <--
    "d": "1"
}
```

So, when it detects that all instances of an index have blank values and sets `"c": "",`, I added `nonresponse[i]=question` (then elsewhere when I'm deciding if a required question is unanswered, I added `if ( $("#"+question).is(":not(:visible)") )` (because only 1 required question is visible at a time so no use complaining about unanswered required questions the user wasn't asked).